# unreadable SD Card (data recovery?)

Tags: lubuntu, data-recovery, sd-card, data-loss

My SanDisk Ultra 128GB SD MicroSDXC Card is suddenly unreadable with both my Laptop and my Smartphone. Meaning that nothing happens when I plug the card in. Checked both devices successfully with another SDXC Card.

Is there any way to access and recover the data on the unreadable SDXC Card? (Actually just a few pictures. I have most of the data backed up. But not the pictures, would be too bad to lose them)

- Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (i686)
- Distribution      : Ubuntu 16.04.1
  LTS
- Computer (Name        : xxxxx-) Vostro-A860
- Desktop Environment       : LXDE
  (Lubuntu)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the card is unreadable in any system or reader (phone, other computer, etc) then the internal components likely are either dead or damaged.  There is no (affordable or reliable) way to recover the data from the card if the system can't read it.

Comment: SanDisk/Customer service
1 (866) 726-3475